# Заменить загрузочный сектор Windows

Tags: windows, bat

Мне нужно, чтобы вместо загрузки Windows при старте компьютера на экране появлялось, предположим, какое-либо изображение. Возможно ли (и если возможно, то как) написать скрипт на bat/vbs для замены загрузочного сектора? Файл с изображением находится в одной папке со скриптом и называется `foo.jpg`.

> *Не планирую и вам не советую использовать это для нанесения вреда чьему-либо ПК!*

Comment: Не надо менять загрузочный сектор. Просто зарегистрируй ещё одну загрузочную систему и отправь на запуск приложения (причём работающего без поддержки со стороны ОС). И сделай её дефолтной. А ещё лучше - просто вставить запуск приложения, отображающего картинку в полноэкранке и модально, в автозагрузку.

Comment: А кто будет показывать ваш jpg, если не Windows?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, можно же напрямую в видеопамять писать

Comment: Может и не нужно изобретать велосипед. Почему не устраивают готовые решения ? Есть открытый проект [HackBGRT](https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT/), есть описание процедуры кастомизации на сайте производителя [MS Docs: Replace the startup logo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unbranded-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте немного порассуждаем.

Вы говорите "есть файл jpg, я хочу, чтобы эту картинку вместо запуска операционной системы показали на мониторе."

Оба. Файл. Часть файловой системы, то есть, одной из подсистем OS. Показали на мониторе. Который подключен к графической карте, которая управляется драйвером операционной системы. И делает это - барабанная дробь! - некая программа, которая запущена, опять же, под операционной системой!

В общем, по некотором размышлении, видим, что совсем без OS обойтись трудно.

Но есть способы сократить промежуток "файл-монитор".

Варианты есть такие:

1. Почти ничего не менять, вставить файл в автозагрузку существующей OS. Это же Вам посоветовали в комментариях.
2. Поставить отдельную "легковесную систему" - что то, что будет загружаться, в чем нет приложений, а есть только средства для показа файла на мониторе. Какй то очень простой Linux или, не к ночи упомянута, ReactOS.
3. Можно "заморочиться по взрослому", взять одну из множества "OS на дискете" (погуглите, есть такие) и немного допилить её, чтобы она делала то, что Вам нужно.

Все зависит от кол-ва усилий, которые Вы готовы потратить. Правда, в процессе удастся узнать много нового...